# Why is play to compile all java code when I just change a class of java?

Tags: playframework, sbt

Using a version of play 2.3.3, when I change one java class, why is play to compile all java code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't recompile all Java code. Play uses an incremental compiler built on top of a batch compiler([SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/)).

**Long story short:**

When you change a file, **ideally**, the compiler does a **TWO STEP** job:

1. searches for the modified files
2. checks what other files(dependencies) need recompilation(based on STEP1)

BUT(there's always a but) sometimes the dependencies can be realy complex so additional steps are required. This process can be optimized by following some best practices(see the provided link below).

So, how much it actually recompiles, depends on the nature of the changes and the intricacies of the dependencies.

There's a more detailed discussion on the topic [in the Play Framework Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/wBCuWbzLq_A).

Cheers!

Comment: Indeed Play uses a custom watch monitor, but then incremental compilation goes through SBT. That is to say, compilation trigger is in some way specific to Play, but then what's compiled is not as SBT is still responsible to detect what need to be in this field.

Comment: As soon as there is code change, what's re-compiled is not specific to Play. Need to be stated clearly.